# How to Show Response Error body Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, http, webpack, error-handling

If user type wrong data the error is: 
[image: If user type wrong data the error is:]

I want to show blue marked "errors" in alert. I tried with this code:

```
    create(doctor: Doctor): Promise<Response | Doctor> {
    return this.http
    .post(this.doctorsUrl, JSON.stringify(doctor), {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => doctor)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response): Promise<Response>{
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    alert(error.json());
    return Promise.reject(error);
 }
```

But I am getting object Object only. How to get this "errors"? Should I create new class for error?

Greetings, Bartek :)

Comment: Did you try `JSON.parse(error.json()._body).errors[0]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert JSON object to string using JSON.stringify()

> alert(JSON.stringify(error.json()));

Or you can get the Value from error object as

> alert(error._body.type) // will give you type=error

Comment: thank's that help me A LOT, I get whole response, that is big step forward! but when error._body show that property _body does not exists on type response...

Comment: Try to console error and check what it prints, from that you can construct appropriate alert message.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the string into an object, using `JSON.parse()` method,

```
JSON.parse(error.json()._body).errors[0]
```

will give you the error message alone. (If I'm not mistaken, else pardon me)

Comment: That was helpful. but I dont need the _body here :) solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to handle the error or show the error message.

**Method 1:**

```
let message= JSON.parse(error._body).errors;
```

You can directly show the message in front end  but this is applicable only in the single error case.

**Method 2:**   when error is in object form

```
let message = "";
errorMessage='';
for (let prop in JSON.parse(error._body).errors) {message +=JSON.parse(error._body).errors[prop][0] + "\n"; this.errorMessage = message;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this line of code

```
let obj :ValidationError = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error.error));
```

stringify : convert json to string string

Answer (score 0):

This works with me

```
const errorObjectAsString = JSON.stringify(error);
```